# Simplifying $\arctan\frac{2}{1^2} + \arctan\frac{2}{2^2} + \arctan\frac{2}{3^2}+ \cdots+\arctan\frac{2}{n^2}$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

$$S = \arctan\frac{2}{1^2} + \arctan\frac{2}{2^2} + \arctan\frac{2}{3^2}+ \cdots+\arctan\frac{2}{n^2}$$

I tried to simplify this summation by substituting $\arctan(2/k^2)$ to $a_k$ so that$\ \tan(a_k) = 2/k^2$, then using the sum of tangent formula, but it didn't work. Can someone help me how to simplify this summation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac2{n^2}=\dfrac{n+1-(n-1)}{1+(n-1)(n+1)}$$

Comment: You should add the not-well-known-formula-by-present-day-students $\tan(a-b)=\dfrac{\tan a - \tan b}{1+\tan a \tan b}$

Comment: @JeanMarie, You are saying OP is trying to solve the current problem w/o knowing the basic formula  :)

Comment: @lab Bhattacharjee Thank you, sir... What a unique IDEA!! Thank you for your generosity :) I think I will always transform $2/n^2 $ formula afterwards :))

Comment: [+1] Besides for the formula...

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm so sorry for the lack of my knowledge, but I actually know the sum/difference formula of tangents, sir. I hope you don't look down on others again since there are a lot of intelligent people in the world :)

Comment: @Ivan_Raki What make you think that ? First of all, intelligence and knowledge are two different things...   I took as reference the (low-level) knowledge about trigonometry in my own country.